# Spring security example with jdbc api

Tags: struts2, spring-security

I downloaded appfuse struts2+spring secutiry which is using the hibernate.
I want to know how to convert it into jdbc api or provide other sample example which is developed using simple jdbc api.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need JDBC api and what's wrong with hibernate?

Comment: Roman thanks for quick response.
I don't have experience in hibernate so i want this to be done using jdbc api

Comment: The AppFuse uses three-tired architecture that consists of a data layer, service layer, and a web layer. One more layer is required it's a security layer that cross over all other layers. The Hibernate is very popular on the data layer, but you can chose any other ORM framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved quite easily.All you need is to write implementation of  "GenericDao" interface. Appfuse provides GenericDao hibernate implementation called "GenericDaoHibernate" out of the box, which I encourage you to use instead. Anyway, this is what I suggest:

1. Create a package called ...dao.jdbc
2. Create a JDBC implementation class for GenericDao Interface called
   "GenericDaoJdbc" in above package. It may initially looks like below in code section.
3. Then you can continue implementing the rest of the interface methods with jdbcTemplate instance by getJdbcTemplate()

> ```
> public class GenericDaoJdbcTemplate<T, PK extends Serializable> 
>                               implements GenericDao<T, PK> {
>   @Autowired
>   private DataSource dataSource;
>   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
>
>   protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
>   private Class<T> persistentClass;
>
>   public GenericDaoJdbcTemplate(final Class<T> persistentClass) {
>         this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
>   }
>
>   protected JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
>       if (jdbcTemplate == null) return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
>
>       return jdbcTemplate;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public List<T> getAll() {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       return null;
>   }
>   ...
> ```
>
> }